# frame animation draws out of the center

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

When I pull to refresh list, my progress bar animation looks really weird. You can see screen shot below.

I used 8 frames to imitate the refreshing animations on indeterminate mode, but the refreshing circle animation draws incorrectly.
I want to know why this can happen, and why this is a dark line at the bottom of the circle.

progress bar statement

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/head_contentLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="15dip">

        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/head_arrowImageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/pulltorefresh_arrow"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingTop="10dip"
                android:paddingBottom="15dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip">

            <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/head_progressBar"
                    style="@style/loading_small"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/head_tipsTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/pull_to_refresh_pull_label"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/head_lastUpdatedTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="10sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

style files

```
<style name="loading_small" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@anim/pull_to_refresh_header_loading</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">41dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">41dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

items for animation list

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<animation-list android:oneshot="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:duration="100" android:drawable="@drawable/loading_0" />
    <item android:duration="100" android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1" />
    <item android:duration="100" android:drawable="@drawable/loading_2" />
    <item android:duration="100" android:drawable="@drawable/loading_3" />
    <item android:duration="100" android:drawable="@drawable/loading_4" />
    <item android:duration="100" android:drawable="@drawable/loading_5" />
    <item android:duration="100" android:drawable="@drawable/loading_6" />
    <item android:duration="100" android:drawable="@drawable/loading_7" />
</animation-list>
```

weird refreshing circles
[image]

one of the frame used to assemble the circle.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove padding of the frame layout. and set hight and width to wrap content and crop ur images for respective **(width and height to 15 and 21 dp respectively)** size. cos it will help u for device compatibility..

try this

```
<style name="loading_small" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@anim/pull_to_refresh_header_loading</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">41dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">41dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I tested this method with no luck. When I tried to change the width and height to `13dip`, the progress bar can correctly show the frame by frame around the center, but the problem is `13dip` width is way small, looks like a dot, really wired.

Comment: I tried to delete paddings, but still can not fix it. Thanks for your pantience

Comment: After delete the padding and change the width and height to 15 and 21 dp respectively in styles xml, the problems was fixed.